# What can be said about coverings when there is no universal cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm studying problems of classification and existence of coverings.

There is a property that states that a universal cover is a covering of any other cover of the space. Also, in some sense one can classify the coverings of a space up to isomorphism when there exists a universal cover because there is a bijective isomorphism: $$\Delta_x: C(X) \to S_c(\Pi_1(X,x))$$ where $S_c$ represents certain conjugacy class for the fundamental group. Then one solves the existence of this universal cover when the covered space is semi-locally simply connected.

What about the reciprocal? If there isn't a universal cover what can be said about the existence of any cover of the space?

Ideally, I would be looking for examples of different situation that may occur.

Comment: I don’t know, good question.  Spaces without them are pretty gross.

Comment: @Randall you mean they're big in size? what kind of spaces do you have in mind?

Comment: Oh, I meant very messy or ill-behaved.  It’s an Americanism.

Comment: for Hawaaian earring, there doesn't exists any universal cover. You can play with it.

Comment: You could look at 10.5.1  of my book "Topology and Groupoids" which gives local conditions on a space $X$ if there is a covering map  $p: \widetilde{X} \to  X$. What is not attempted is the construction of examples satisfying such more general conditions, but not semi locally simply connected!